# What is the expiration date of WO PCT applications?

Tags: international

If the patent is applied in India, but the country I would like to use the technology is included in Designated States, of which country's expiration date do you have to calculate?

Application number: WO2012IB57364 20121217
Priority number(s): IN2011MU03650 20111224

and no other applications.

Edit: it is WO2013093751 PACKAGING FOR LINEZOLID

> Pub. No.:       WO/2013/093751      International Application No.:      PCT/IB2012/057364
>   Publication Date:   27.06.2013  International Filing Date:  17.12.2012

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a PCT application and they, nominally, expire 30 months from the earliest claimed priority date. However that varies by the specific country and [WIPO has a page](http://www.wipo.int/pct/en/texts/time_limits.html) that lists the time limit by jurisdiction. In that table you will see that many places have a super script to the number of months. These indicate locations that allow late entry into the national stage under various circumstances. You will need to find out if the country you want to practice the technology in has any leeway in their 30 or 31 month deadline.

The priory date of this application seems to be

> Priority Data:    3650/MUM/2011       24.12.2011      IN

Using the PCT deadline calculator the 30 month deadline would be June 24 2014.

Comment: I appreciate for your answer.  The patent is the following.  http://patentscope.wipo.int/search/en/detail.jsf?docId=WO2013093751&recNum=165&docAn=IB2012057364&queryString=opioid&maxRec=12057  This is a patent about medical drug.  I will try to find the paticular page on WIPO later on.

Comment: @kiwi - I have edited my answer to have more information and be more helpful.